# How to extract data subsets from a text data file in Python

Tags: python, file

I have a text file where the relevant data (rows x columns) only appear between "start" and "end" key words. See below. I want to write a code that can extract these data subsets. If a line starts with "start" followed by data, but NOT followed by a subsequent "end" key word, then I want to ignore that data. In my example below, data1 and data3 are relevant, but data2 is NOT because it is not enclosed by "start" and "end" key words.

```
start
data1 (matrix of data) /relevant because data1 is enclosed by "start" and "end"
end
start
data2 (matrix of data) /not relevant because there is no "end"
. 
start
data3 (matrix of data) /relevant for same reason as for data1
end
.
.
and so on
```

I thought I could start with:

```
with open(file_path,'r') as file:

    text = file.readlines()
    start_indexes = []
    end_indexes = []

    for i, line in enumerate(text):
        if line.startswith('start'):
            start_indexes.append(i)
        elif line.startswith('end'):
            end_indexes.append(i)

    for i in range(len(start_indexes)):
        for j in range(len(end_indexes)):
            if (start_indexes[i] < end_indexes[j] < start_indexes[i+1]):
                print(start_indexes[i],end_indexes[j])
```

The above code gives me both the starting line numbers and the ending line numbers where there is relevant data. Here is where I am somewhat stuck. How do I now pull the relevant data? In my example below, it would be data1, data3. Am I approaching the problem the "correct" way? Should I resort to pandas? Is there a more efficient and direct way?

Comment: Is the line format always ether: `start; data; start` or `start; data; end`?  Please post your expected output for the example input.

Answer (score 0):

## Nested For Loops?

You're going through every combination of start and end ranges. You only want the ones that correspond to the same piece of data.

Replace your for loop with something like this:

```
for start, end in zip(start_indexes, end_indexes):
    print(text[start + 1:end])
```

`zip(a, b, ...)` returns a new list with the columns of `a, b, ...`, essentially giving `[(a[0], b[0], ...), (a[1], b[1], ...), ...]`. You go through each column of `start_indexes, end_indexes`, giving you corresponding start and end values, and then you use list slice accessing to get the data at those lines.

Comment: Thanks. I need to understand zip a little better, but I do want to mention that start_indexes and end_indexes are lists having different lengths. A chunk of data is NOT always enclosed by "start" and "end". Only if the test is successful, then we'll have data enclosed by "start" and "end". If there is an unsuccessful test, in the data file, we get "start" followed by some incomplete data, then NOT followed by "end", but by another "start" where a second testing attempt begins. If the second attempt is successful, we'll then get "end" at the end.

Comment: @Murchak Note that `zip` always returns a rectangular matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I would use another way by reading the file only sequentially (this assumes that the data in a "start"-"end"-block isn't too large). I would create a `data` variable to collect data of the current block (regardless if relevant or not) and a `state` variable with state transitions.

Some pseudo-Python:

```
if state == OUTSIDE_BLOCK and line.startswith('start'):
    state = INSIDE_BLOCK
elif state == INSIDE_BLOCK and <line contains data>:
    <Add to data variable>
elif state == INSIDE_BLOCK and line.startswith('end'):
    state = OUTSIDE_BLOCK
    <Process collected data>
elif state == INSIDE_BLOCK and line.startswith('start'):
    <Throw away possibly collected data because it was irrelevant>
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally feel regex is the best way to handle such situations:

`import re
woof0='''start
data1 (matrix of data) /relevant because data1 is enclosed by "start" and "end"
end
start
data2 (matrix of data) /not relevant because there is no "end"
. 
start
data3 (matrix of data) /relevant for same reason as for data1
end
.
.
and so on
'''
re.findall(r'start(\sdata.*|\Sdata.*)\nend',woof0)`

**Output:**

`['\ndata1 (matrix of data) /relevant because data1 is enclosed by "start" and "end"',
 '\ndata3 (matrix of data) /relevant for same reason as for data1']`

Comment: OP specified that `start` followed by `data` followed by `end` is NOT text to be *captured*.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. I think you may have misunderstood the structure of the data. The data portion does not have the word data in it. It is any number of lines where each line (row) is an observation, and each line contains many columns (attributes). I am not sure how Regex would help.

Comment: Got it! does the data appear in consistent form i.e. csv or space delimited?

Answer (score 0):

Setup:

```
s = '''start
data1 (matrix of data) /relevant because data1 is enclosed by "start" and "end"
end
start
data2 (matrix of data) /not relevant because there is no "end"
start
data3 (matrix of data) /relevant for same reason as for data1
end
start
data4 blah
'''
import io
f = io.StringIO(s)
```

Iterate once through the file, testing what each line starts with; figure out the logic required to place valid data blocks in a sub list and append them to a results list ...

```
result = []
sub = []

for line in f:
    if line.startswith('start'):
        # possible new data block
        if sub:
            # if it isn't empty it must contain
            # a start --> data block with no end
            result.append(sub)
            sub = []
        sub = [line]
    elif line.startswith('end'):
        # start over
        sub = []
    elif line.startswith('data'):
        sub.append(line)
    else:
        # for lines that don't startwith data, start or end - if any 
        sub.append(line)

if sub:
    # start --> data --> EOF or end of string
    result.append(sub)
```